# Save the results of the date difference on PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, diff

how to save the results of the date difference to be saved to the database ?

```
    public function save(){
       $item      = $this->input->post('item');
       $date_in   = $this->input->post('date_in'); //date in
       $date_out  = $this->input->post('date_out'); // date out
       $hasil = $date_in->diff($date_out); 
       //echo $hasil->format('%a'); I will save these results to the database


    $data_insert = array(
        'item'             => $item,
        'date_in'          => $date_in,
        'date_out'         => $date_out,
        'selisih'          => $hasil
      );
//url save
}
```

Comment: what is the framework, ci or laravel?

Comment: codeigniter, sorry :D

Comment: `$this->db->insert('mytable',  $data_insert);`?

Comment: yes I know, what I mean is how to save the results of the difference in date,when I save it, I get an error Call to a member function diff () on string. thanks

Comment: because string don't have `diff` method, you need to change it to DateTime.`(new DateTime($date_in))->diff(new DateTime($date_out))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String don't have method `diff`, `diff` is the method of [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/zh/class.datetime.php), you need to change string to DateTime.

And it will return [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object, you can get the total days by [format('%a')](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) and insert to database;

```php
$hasil = (new DateTime($date_in))->diff(new DateTime($date_out));
$hasil = $hasil->format('%a');

$data_insert = array(
  'item'             => $item,
  'date_in'          => $date_in,
  'date_out'         => $date_out,
  'selisih'          => $hasil
);
$this->db->insert('mytable', $data_insert);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get difference you can get it with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) easily using `diffInDays` Example code for you :

```
$first = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $date_in);
$second = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $date_out);
$diff_in_days = $second->diffInDays($first);
```

Or get it without Carbon :

```
$first = new DateTime($date_in);
$second = new DateTime($date_out);
$interval = $first->diff($second);
```

Comment: how to post $hasil to database? error Call to a member function diff () on string

Comment: @nanayaja Check your collection column format. and use [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent)